# $f \in C([-1,1])$, given $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)x^ndx = 0$ for $n = 0,1,2,...$ then $f(x)=0, \ \forall x \in [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity, weierstrass-approximation

> Let $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[-1,1]$.
>
> Assume $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)x^ndx = 0$ for $n = 0,1,2,...$
>
> Then show $f(x)=0, \ \forall x \in [-1,1]$

I would like to use Weierstrass Approximation Theorem (WAT) to prove this. Here is my incomplete attempt:

$f$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$ so by WAT $\exists$ a sequence polynomials $p_1, p_2, p_3,...,p_n,...$ s.t.

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} |p_n - f| = 0$, so 
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-1}^{1}|f-p_n| = 0$.

Now, I would like to show $\int_{-1}^{1} f^2 = 0$ and from there I would like to conclude that $f=0$.
So,
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1} (f(x))^2 dx & = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)f(x) \\
& = \int_{-1}^{1} \left[ f(x)f(x)-f(x)p_n(x)+f(x)p_n(x) \right] dx \\
& = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x) (f(x) - p_n(x)) dx + \int_{-1}^{1}f(x) p_n(x)dx
\end{align}

$\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) p_n(x) dx = 0$ by the hypothesis since $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x) x^n dx = 0$ for **all** $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

So that leaves me to show,

$\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)(f(x)-p_n(x)) = 0$. I know $\lim_{n \to \infty}|f-p_n|=0$, but I am not clear how I can use this to show the integral is $0$. First of all, we are working with a fixed $n$, and second of all the limit of absolute difference is $0$.

Should I start the proof with limits and show the integral is arbitrarily small?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)||f(x)-p_{n}(x)|dx&\leq\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|f(x)-p_{n}(x)|\int_{-1}^{1}|f(x)|dx\\
&=K\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|f(x)-p_{n}(x)|,
\end{align*}
where $K$ is the integral, which is a finite number, now the supremum can be made arbitrarily small by Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused about the phrasing of the full proof. I am working with fixed $n$ here and while what you wrote is true, I can't say the left hand side is $=0$ without taking a limit somewhere.

Comment: You let $p_{n}$ be such that $\sup|f-p_{n}|<1/n$, and then taking limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: So $\displaystyle\int f^{2}\leq K/n$, taking limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ the integral is then zero.

Comment: So $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f^2 = 0 \implies \int f^2 = 0$?

Comment: Of course, the integral is constant with respect to $n$.

Comment: And we can take supremum out of the integral like that because we can replace $|f-p_n|$ with a constant bigger than it, right?

Comment: Actually one compares inside the integral the term with the supremum, and the supremum is constant, then you just take it out.

Comment: Thank you! Beautifully explained.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}|f(x)-p_n(x)|=0,$$
we know for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $\forall n> N$ 
$$|f-p_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 M},$$
where $M:=\max_{[-1,1]} |f(x)|$.

Hence
$$\left|\int_{-1}^1f(x) \left(f(x)-p_n(x)\right)\,dx \right|<\frac{\epsilon}{2 M}\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|\,dx \leq\epsilon,\quad \forall n>N.$$